# mongod.conf - bindIp refuses connection

Tags: mongodb

I have two servers - one running the API I want to access the DB from and one running the actual database.

This is my mongod.conf file content:

```
# network interfaces
net:
  bindIp: 165.227.236.198
  port: 27017
```

This is the output from the `ifconfig` command on my ubuntu server:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr be:08:9e:b1:e7:d7  
          inet addr:165.227.236.198  Bcast:165.227.239.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::bc08:9eff:feb1:e7d7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:14502 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13741 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:33725605 (33.7 MB)  TX bytes:1816546 (1.8 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:80 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:80 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:5920 (5.9 KB)  TX bytes:5920 (5.9 KB)
```

The API is bound on port 80. Now when I remove the `bindIp` setting from the `mongod.conf` file the database connects as expected, but when I bind the ip, the database refuses the connection.

EDIT: the database refuses the connection because the service fails. This is the output from the logs (not really informative):

> ● mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented
>   database    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service;
>   enabled; vendor preset: enabled)    Active: failed (Result: exit-code)
>   since Mon 2018-07-02 11:04:43 UTC; 3s ago
>        Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual   Process: 13473 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited,
>   status=48)  Main PID: 13473 (code=exited, status=48)
>
> Jul 02 11:04:43 minimalistic-ledger-db systemd[1]: Started
>   High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database. Jul 02
>   11:04:43 minimalistic-ledger-db systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main
>   process exited, code=exited, status=48/n/a Jul 02 11:04:43
>   minimalistic-ledger-db systemd[1]: mongod.service: Unit entered failed
>   state. Jul 02 11:04:43 minimalistic-ledger-db systemd[1]:
>   mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

EDIT2: this is the error from the mongodb log:

> 2018-07-02T11:04:43.444+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {
>   config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "165.227.236.198", port:
>   27017 }, storage: { $ 2018-07-02T11:04:43.475+0000 E NETWORK 
>   [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed Cannot assign requested
>   address for socket: 165.227.236.198:27017 2018-07-02T11:04:43.475+0000
>   E NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to set up sockets during startup.
>   2018-07-02T11:04:43.475+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set
>   up listener: InternalError: Failed to set up sockets

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason for this error could be that the network interface is not configured properly i think, or the IP address is already being used bya nother instance.

Try this out:

1. Verify that the network interface is properly configured and that
   the IP address is available, try running ifconfig on the server.
   ifconfig is a command used in Linux-based operating systems (such as
   Ubuntu) to view and configure network interfaces and their settings,
   including IP addresses, netmasks, and network device names.
2. Check if any other services are already using the specified IP
   address and port combination. You can do this by running the command
   sudo lsof -i :27017 on the server. If another service running on the
   same port, and you should either stop that service or choose a
   different port for MongoDB.
3. If none above helped you could try to change the bind IP
   address to 127.0.0.1 to bind MongoDB to the localhost interface.
   This will allow you to connect to the database from the same server
   using the loopback IP address.

If not try to keep checking to the log for any other message that could be useful.
Sorry the delay